# Having issues printing the count of tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I want to print out the number of rows that have been added to my tableview in OrderNumberLabel, for example if someone has added 4 items to the table view i want it to calculate and print out the number 4 in the OrderNumberLabel. Is this possible to do? I tried a few ways but nothing is working for me, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var OrderNumberLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var CostLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfitsLabel: RoundedLabel2!


    @IBOutlet weak var itemTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pricesTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var salepriceTextField: UITextField!

    var items: [ItemRow] = []

  struct ItemRow: Codable {
        var item: String
        var price: Double
        var salePrice: Double

        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {case item, price, salePrice}

        var profit : Double {
           return salePrice - price
        }

        var cost : Double {
           return price
        }
    }


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            load()
            updateProfitLabel()
            updateCostLabel()


        }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
         return true
     }

    func save(){
        if let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "Saved")
        }

    }

    func load(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "Saved") {
            items = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([ItemRow].self, from: data)


        }

    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        insertNewItems()
        save()


    }




        func insertNewItems() {

            let price = Double(pricesTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
            let salePrice = Double(salepriceTextField.text!) ?? 0.0

            let newVideoRow = ItemRow(item: itemTextField.text!, price: price, salePrice: salePrice)
            items.append(newVideoRow)
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

            updateProfitLabel()
            updateCostLabel()
            itemTextField.text = ""
            pricesTextField.text = ""
            salepriceTextField.text = ""
            view.endEditing(true)
        }

    func updateProfitLabel() {
       let profitTotal = items.map{$0.profit}.reduce(0.0, +)
       ProfitsLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", profitTotal)
    }

    func updateCostLabel() {
       let costTotal = items.map{$0.cost}.reduce(0.0, +)
       CostLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", costTotal)
    }



    }





    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

             let ItemTitle = items[indexPath.row]

               let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell
               cell.itemLabel.text = ItemTitle.item
               cell.priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", ItemTitle.price)
               cell.saleLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", ItemTitle.salePrice)
                tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1.0)
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
               return cell
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
           if editingStyle == .delete {
                items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                save()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You just want `items.count` to be displayed in `OrderNumberLabel`? (Which, by the way, should be `orderNumberLabel` - variables and constants start with a lower case letter by convention

Comment: basically yes, just want it to display the count of the table view in the label

Comment: If so, just set `items.count` to `orderNumberLabel.text`

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'Int' thats the error i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
orderNumberLabel.text = String(items.count)
```

Comment: If you want to save it to user defaults, simply do: Userdefaults.standard.set(orderNumberLabel.text, forKey: "ItemsPurchased"). Then to fetch it from user defaults: orderNumberLabel.text = Userdefaults.standard.string(forKey: "ItemsPurchased").